# Tomcat not starting with 64bit java

Tags: java, tomcat, 64-bit

I am using Windows 7 and have recently installed Eclipse Helios(64bit).

I was controlling a local installation of Tomcat7 from my Eclipse install, and Eclipse and tomcat were starting correctly. However, I was getting some errors with the M2Eclipse plugin and realise the JDK I was using was not 64bit, so updated my JDK to the 64 bit.

Unfortunately, since updating the JDK to 64bit my tomcat will no longer start, and instead I get the following error in my stack trace:

```
02-May-2011 21:02:38 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: threadAllocatedMemorySupport
    at sun.management.VMManagementImpl.initOptionalSupportFields(Native Method)
    at sun.management.VMManagementImpl.<clinit>(VMManagementImpl.java:47)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactory.<clinit>(ManagementFactory.java:468)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:184)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:406)
```

Has any one else come across this or know what the issue might be?

---------------EDIT------------------------

Furthemore, I have started the local tomcat using startup.bat and it started fine, but then when trying to access the manager I get a java.lang.outOfMemoryError permgen Space error (whihc i wasnt getting before- was all running ok before the jdk upgrade)

Comment: are you using the 64 bit tomcat?

Comment: @Wes, I doubt it if the OP just upgraded to 64 bit java...

Comment: sorry, did mean to add that - yes, I am running the 64bit tomcat (re-checked eclipse, tomcat, java were all running 64bit versions)

Comment: Are you sure Tomcat is really using the 64-bit version of JDK you have just installed? Could you double check system paths / JAVA_HOME. Maybe it's the case of 64-bit Tomcat trying to use a 32-bit JDK?

Comment: have checked JAVA_HOME and path env variables and both are referring to the new 64bit install

Comment: Ok, the problem was, although I had updated Eclipse prefs to use the 64bitJDK, the JRE system libraries were still pointing to the old JDK - I have never come across this before, and pretty sure that when I have updated the JDK before it has automatically refreshed the JRE library list as well..

Comment: @rhinds - why don't you post your findings as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found the problem

The guys above were on the right lines in terms of investigating the JDK version being used was correct.

What had happened was, although I had updated Eclipse prefs to use the 64bitJDK, the JRE system libraries were still pointing to the old JDK - I have never come across this before, and pretty sure that when I have updated the JDK before it has automatically refreshed the JRE library list as well. I then removed all the JRE system libraries from the list and refreshed and it then re-populated with the libraries from the 64bit jdk

Comment: Got a similar issue, cause was the same, Eclipse mixed up libraries from different JDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the wrong tcnative is installed? Get rid of it from bin directory and see what happens

Comment: Tried deleting the tcNative dll from the bin dir but still no joy

Comment: What happens if you start tomcat directly - tomcat7.exe (you can use tomcat7w.exe to edit the memory allocation, startup params.